# Regex string extraction

Tags: regex

I am stumped working on a regular expression.  So here is the sample text I am working with to run my regex on.

```
21;#ABC - A8 (ZYWX) DEF - S123 CODE ASD4 - PL_MN - 567aB - 987aL 6.8R WHHHA StackOverflow.file;42;#ABC_9876f_KIIIt_QW_blew34.files;43;#ABC-LKP RT00-44-33 876aY@2200foo.bats;45;#Javax_P3_2345_123lE_451rP_Regex_Expression_Help.rewa;26;#GHJ - AQS 231-4_330-9 TIIIx Python JavaScript.text;
```

Here is the end result I am looking for after running the regex:

```
ABC - A8 (ZYWX) DEF - S123 CODE ASD4 - PL_MN - 567aB - 987aL 6.8R WHHHA StackOverflow  
ABC_9876f_KIIIt_QW_blew34  
ABC-LKP RT00-44-33 876aY@2200foo  
Javax_P3_2345_123lE_451rP_Regex_Expression_Help  
GHJ - AQS 231-4_330-9 TIIIx Python JavaScript
```

A total of 5 matches.

The regular expression I have thus far is:

```
[A-Z][()\w\s@-]*
```

This regex isn't working though because the first line in my results ends up getting split in two pieces at the period.  I am unable to come up with a solution as to how to fix this.  I am fairly new to regex so any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: So the `.` after `StackOverflow` is a delimiter, but the `.` in `6.8R` is not?

Comment: It looks like all your matches end with `.<word>;`, is that correct? Use a positive lookahead to match that.

Comment: Yes that is a correct.

Comment: You could just use regex split to split on `;42;#`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like each match ends with `.`, followed by a word, followed by `;`. Use a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match a string followed by that.

```
[A-Z][()\w\s@\-.]*(?=\.\w+;)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/UYorAg/1)

Comment: `[A-Z][()\w\s@\-.]*(?=\.\w+;)` <- errors out without escaped `-`

Comment: Yes.  That works.  Thank you for your help and such quick response.  Looks like I have some learning to do on lookaheads.